# Android: Binary XML file line Error inflating class

Tags: android, xml, layout, binary, inflate-exception

I've been trying to load a list of records from a database to a screen but there seems to be a problem when the app gets the data and tries to display it on the screen. I read that sometimes this type of error is thrown when displaying large images and such but I have no images and tried some other solutions I've read about. Any input is appreciated!

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.blackfrogweb.macrotracker, PID: 16129
  android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line 23: Binary XML file line 23: Error inflating class <unknown>
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
  at com.blackfrogweb.macrotracker.FavsCustomAdapter.getView(FavsCustomAdapter.java:38)
  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346)
  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1876)
  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:702)
  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:763)
  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1671)
  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2148)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2678)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2171)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1931)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Here is the xml of the layout Im trying to "inflate".

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:gravity="left">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/favorite_name"
                android:textColor="@color/colorText"
                android:textSize="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/favorite_cal"
                android:textSize="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/colorText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/favorite_fat"
                android:textSize="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/colorText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/favorite_carb"
                android:textSize="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/colorText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/favorite_prot"
                android:textSize="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/colorText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="right">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/add"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/edit"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/delete"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"/>
            </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Since I'm not really sure where the error is happening, I'm not sure what piece of code to post -and I don't want to make this unreadable.

Comment: check the Binary XML file line 23 .

Comment: For other devs this is also cause by xml fonts https://stackoverflow.com/a/47987602/5710872

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currenty you are setting `?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium` to `android:textSize`.
You should replace the attribute with  `android:textAppearance`.

> Change
>
> ```
> android:textSize="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
> ```
>
> TO
>
> ```
> android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
> ```

OR

Set direct value to `android:textSize`like

```
android:textSize="10sp"
```

Comment: It works well but I don't know why "android:textSize="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" is wrong...?

Comment: @TeachMeJava textSize is expecting a size value(px, dp, sp, in and mm). "?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" is combination of Base text color, typeface, size, and style. So we cannot use it for textsize.

Answer (score 3):

```
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
```

I removed from my xml file my problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

You have not closed the tag properly.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:gravity="left">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/favorite_name"
                android:textColor="@color/colorText"
                android:textSize="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/favorite_cal"
                android:textSize="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/colorText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/favorite_fat"
                android:textSize="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/colorText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/favorite_carb"
                android:textSize="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/colorText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/favorite_prot"
                android:textSize="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/colorText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="right">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/add"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/edit"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/delete"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are getting the `Exception` for bellow line of your `<TextView/>`.

```
 android:textSize="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
```

Try with

```
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void getDetailFood(String foodId) {
foods.child(foodId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
try {
Food food = dataSnapshot.getValue(Food.class);
**Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(food.getImage())
                        .into(foodd_image);**
(Iam getting NullPOinter Exception)`enter code here`
collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(food.getName());
food_price.setText(food.getPrice());
food_description.setText(food.getDescription());
food_name.setText(food.getName());
}
catch (Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}

}
```

Comment: pls add some explanation to your solution why this is correct or what you're doing as only code answers are discouraged by stackoverflow