# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class Button

Tags: java, android, xml

I am following a course on Audacity, and decided to type out all the code, but then I run into an error when I try run the app.

I get the following error:

```
        10-27 19:17:41.871 26679-26679/com.example.vhuhwavho.friendlychat W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41bbec08)
    10-27 19:17:41.871 26679-26679/com.example.vhuhwavho.friendlychat E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.vhuhwavho.friendlychat, PID: 26679
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.vhuhwavho.friendlychat/com.example.vhuhwavho.friendlychat.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class Button
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2334)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class Button
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
    at com.example.vhuhwavho.friendlychat.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x1
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:327)
    at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getColor(TintTypedArray.java:163)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ThemeUtils.getThemeAttrColor(ThemeUtils.java:65)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.createDefaultButtonColorStateList(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:584)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getTintList(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:536)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatBackgroundHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatBackgroundHelper.java:53)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:74)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:67)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:109)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1024)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1081)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:690)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
    at com.example.vhuhwavho.friendlychat.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
    10-27 19:17:46.696 26679-26679/com.example.vhuhwavho.friendlychat I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 26679 SIG: 9
```

Here’s the main activity:

```
package com.example.vhuhwavho.friendlychat;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    public static final String ANONYMOUS = "anonymous";
    public static final int DEFAULT_MSG_LENGTH_LIMIT = 1000;

    private ListView mMessageListView;
    private MessageAdapter mMessageAdapter;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private ImageButton mPhotoPickerButton;
    private EditText mMessageEditText;
    private Button mSendButton;

    private String mUsername;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mUsername = ANONYMOUS;

        // Initialize references to views
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mMessageListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messageListView);
        mPhotoPickerButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.photoPickerButton);
        mMessageEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageEditText);
        mSendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);

        // Initialize message ListView and its adapter
        List<FriendlyMessage> friendlyMessages = new ArrayList<>();
        mMessageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(this, R.layout.item_message, friendlyMessages);
        mMessageListView.setAdapter(mMessageAdapter);

        // Initialize progress bar
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);

        // ImagePickerButton shows an image picker to upload a image for a message
        mPhotoPickerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO: Fire an intent to show an image picker
            }
        });

        // Enable Send button when there's text to send
        mMessageEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if (charSequence.toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                    mSendButton.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    mSendButton.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            }
        });
        mMessageEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(DEFAULT_MSG_LENGTH_LIMIT)});

        // Send button sends a message and clears the EditText
        mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO: Send messages on click

                // Clear input box
                mMessageEditText.setText("");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here’s the `activity_main.xml` in `@layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.vhuhwavho.friendlychat.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/messageListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_message"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/photoPickerButton"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/messageEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sendButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="@string/send_button_label"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here’s the `item_message.xml` in `@layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photoImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messageTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        tools:text="Message" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        tools:text="Name" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here’s the `button_selector.xml` in `@drawale`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="#999999" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:color="@color/colorAccent" android:state_enabled="true"/>
</selector>
```

Here's the `colors.xml` in `@values`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#FF9800</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#E65100</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#2E7D32</color>
    <color name="colorTitle">#ffffff</color>
</resources>
```

Here's the `strings.xml` in `@values`:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Friendly Chat</string>
    <string name="sign_out">Sign Out</string>
    <string name="send_button_label">Send</string>
</resources>
```

Here’s the `styles.xml` in `@values`:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <!--<item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@drawable/button_selector</item>-->
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@drawable/button_selector</item>
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/FriendlyButtonStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FriendlyButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorTitle</item>

    </style>
</resources>
```

Here's the `menu.xml` in `@menu`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/sign_out_menu"
        android:title="@string/sign_out"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

Here's `dimens.xml` in `@values`:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Here's `(w820dp) dimens.xml` in `@values`:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Example customization of dimensions originally defined in res/values/dimens.xml
         (such as screen margins) for screens with more than 820dp of available width. This
         would include 7" and 10" devices in landscape (~960dp and ~1280dp respectively). -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">64dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Please help me solve the error.

Comment: What's on line 42, `MainActivity.java:42`? Because in the posted `MainActivity` class is the line: `mUsername = ANONYMOUS;` which is irrelevant to the error

Comment: 42. setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: Well in your posted code this is line 40, so there are 2 lines missing, can you update please?

Comment: @pleft , done .

Comment: Are you sure this is all the `logcat` errors? Maybe there are some more can you post please?

Comment: Also post your `colours.xml`

Comment: And your `strings.xml` too

Comment: Alright , I think I've posted everything...

Comment: I just compiled and run your code and it works on my Nexus phone. I only removed the `MessageAdapter` stuff. So probably try to uninstall, clean and build/install your app again.

Comment: Alright, will do

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8):

the button selector is the cause of the problem .. if you read the remaining of the exception, the root cause will be mentioned .. as resource id can't be found !

you have to change your button_selector.xml from:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="#999999" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:color="@color/colorAccent" android:state_enabled="true"/>
</selector>
```

to:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="#999999" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorAccent" android:state_enabled="true"/>
</selector>
```

and it will work fine isA.

Answer (score 7):

In my case the background xmls where not inside one drawable directory. I added all of them in drawable hdpi folder and then rebuild the project. That resolved this issue.

This worked for me!

Comment: But the thing is this solution helps me a lot. :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding in **gradle.properties** file this line below ?

```
 android.enableAapt2=false
```

and then restarting the Gradle daemon command line by running

```
./gradlew --stop
```

[https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#optimizations](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0.html)

Comment: At the time, I ran into the same issue and it happened when I upgraded my Android Studio Gradle, so this ^ worked for me. I didn't provide the exact link so I've updated it on my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this help anyone > I got similar crash

`InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class EditText`

in Android 8.0 and 8.1 in release apk
due to **xml fonts** cause I didn't use latest support libs, I update support library version and it's fixed.

xml having

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/sanfranciscodisplay_medium"
        android:hint="@string/enter_email_address"
        android:lines="1"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

My gradle configs

```
BUILD_TOOLS_VER = '26.0.2'

TARGET_SDK_VER = 26
MIN_SDK_VER = 19

SUPPORT_LIBS_VER = '26.1.0' -> '27.0.2' (fix here)
GOOGLE_SERVICES_VER = '11.4.0' -> '11.8.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you declare the drawable file into `v21` or `v24` folder to change this select the `button_selector.xml` file go to the show in menu option file select the cut `button_selector.xml`  file and move into the drawable folder and paste it.

Answer (score -1):

I have got the same issue and I have resolved finally Opening the gradle.properties and added following line:

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: That has been deprecated and removed. Not valid any more!